# electronJS detect when a user's location is out from a certain redius

Tags: javascript, electron

i a developing an app for my firm. i need a way to periodically check a user's location and know if they are out from a certain set radius. i am using svelte as my frontend framework and electronJS. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide what you tried and tell what specific problems you got trying to achieve this.

Comment: i haven't tried anything i am asking where to start and if anybody knows how to do this. i want to periodically check for users location without the app being open.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific but I think [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) can help you. You can use the geolocation api to get the position of the client if the client allows it. With [watchposition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) you can track the users current position.